# Why height 100% doesn't work for the content?

Tags: html, css

In this code I have a sticky footer and a content section above, but why `height:100%` doesn't work for content section?

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  background-color: #116655;
  height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ffcc44;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div>content</div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  My footer
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an actual height on the `html`

```
html {
 position: relative;
  height: 100%; /* not min-height */
}
```

[**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/odfn77a7/1/)

Comment: this doesn't work because my sticky footer overlaps the content. right now footer stays under the content ( if we have much content)

Comment: Then perhaps `position:absolute` is not the best choice for you...but that wasn't your question. Try another "stick footer" option, perhaps  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` on the content as well, then use `top: 0` and `bottom: 60px` this will make the content take up the remaining space. then use `overflow: auto;` to allow scrolling the content;

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/odfn77a7/3/))

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```